# GCP key only valid for 60 days

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am currently downloading manually key jsons for my project but they are valid only 60 days.

Is there a better solution for that? Can I generate key for longer period of time?

I am referring to Automation Service account for BigQuery.

Thanks in advance.

I went through the documentation on the GCP but with no luck.

Comment: What type of GCP key are you referring to? Edit your post to better describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a GCP key with a longer validity period by using the `--valid-before` or `--validity-period` flag when creating the key. For example:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key-name.json --valid-before=2024-10-06T17:27:27Z
```

This will create a key with a validity period of 365 days (1 year).

Alternatively, you can use a service account key rotation tool to automate the process of generating and rotating keys on a regular basis.

**Note:** You cannot extend the validity period of an existing key.